# Stored Procedure to update or insert docs that belong to multiple partition keys

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a list of documents that belong to a partitioned collection. Instead of querying for every document from the .NET client and either do update or insert, I thought I could use a Stored Procedure to accomplish this.

What I did not initially realize is that Stored Procedures are executed in the transaction scope of a single partition key. So I am getting `PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation`.

The thing is that the documents (that I am trying to upsert) may belong to different partitions. How can I accomplish this in the Stored Procedure? In my case, the SP is useless unless it can operate on multiple partitions.

This is how I constructed my SP:

```
function upsertEcertAssignments(ecerts) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();

    // Validate input
    if (!ecerts) throw new Error("The ecerts is null or undefined");
    if (ecerts.length == 0) throw new Error("The ecerts list size is 0");

    // Recursively call the 'process' function
    processEcerts(ecerts, 0);

    function processEcerts(ecerts, index) {
        if (index >= ecerts.length) {
            response.setBody(index);
            return; 
        }               

        var query = {query: "SELECT * FROM DigitalEcerts c WHERE c.code = @code AND c.collectionType = @type", parameters: [{name: "@code", value: ecerts[index].code}, {name: "@type", value: 0}]};
        var isQueryAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, {partitionKey: ecerts[index].code}, function(err, foundDocuments, foundOptions) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (foundDocuments.length > 0) {
                var existingEcert = foundDocuments[0];
                ecerts[index].id = existingEcert.id;
                var isAccepted = __.replaceDocument(existingEcert._self, ecerts[index], function(err, updatedEcert, replacedOptions) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    processEcerts(ecerts, index + 1);        
                });
                if (!isAccepted) {
                    response.setBody(index);                
                }
            } else {
                var isAccepted = __.createDocument(__.getSelfLink(), ecerts[index], function(err, insertedEcert, insertedOptions) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    processEcerts(ecerts, index + 1);        
                });
                if (!isAccepted) {
                    response.setBody(index);                
                }
            }
        });

        if (!isQueryAccepted)
            response.setBody(index);                
    }
}
```

From .NET, if I call it like this, I get the partitionKey value problem:

```
var continuationIndex = await _docDbClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<int>(UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(_docDbDatabaseName, _docDbDigitalEcertsCollectionName, "UpsertDigitalMembershipEcertAssignments"), digitalEcerts);
```

If I call it with a partition key, it works...but it is useless:

```
var continuationIndex = await _docDbClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<int>(UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(_docDbDatabaseName, _docDbDigitalEcertsCollectionName, "UpsertDigitalMembershipEcertAssignments"), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(digitalEcerts[0].Code) }, digitalEcerts.Take(1).ToList());
```

I appreciate any pointer.

Thanks.

Comment: The real question is why did you use a stored procedure and not the Upsert methods provided by the SDK?

Comment: This is because I need the document `id` to do upsert! Unless I am totally wrong, the `id` is how Cosmos knows that the document is the same. The documents that I have are not pulled from Cosmos DB....but they have the same properties. So I end up querying for each doc using the PK and type. If the document exists, I use the id to upsert. This is taking along time especially that I have about 100 docs to partially update..

Comment: The id is not a unique property in CosmosDB. It is only unique inside it's own partition.

Comment: Ok...thank you...but I am not sure I understand. Let us say I have an entity that has the following 3 properties: id = '', code = '123' and type = 0. The `id` is unknown. If I do `upsert`, it will always insert the document because the `id` does not match any existing document ...right? Unless I query first using `code` and `type`, there is no way I know to update or insert. This is my problem. I was hoping that I can do the query and either replace or insert on the server using SP to avoid round trips.

Comment: Are query and type enough to give you a unique `id`? If yes then why don't you make the `id` to be a combination of `code` and `type`?

Comment: Wow....I think this is a great idea and might actually solve my problem using `Upsert`! Thank you sir. I guess SPs were not meant to solve this problem.

Comment: Not sure how to credit you for the answer though.

Comment: Should i just write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sound of it, your unique id is a combination of `code` and `type`. I would recommend making your `id` property to be the combination of two.

This guarantees that your `id` is unique but also eliminates the need to query for it.

Comment: While this solves my problem, it does not, of course, address the issue I encountered in Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 0):

> If the collection the stored procedure is registered against is a
>   single-partition collection, then the transaction is scoped to all the
>   documents within the collection. If the collection is partitioned,
>   then stored procedures are executed in the transaction scope of a
>   single partition key. Each stored procedure execution must then
>   include a partition key value corresponding to the scope the
>   transaction must run under.

You could refer to the description above which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-program-transactions). We can query documents cross partitions via setting `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` to `true` in `FeedOptions` parameter. However, the `RequestOptions` doesn't have such properties against executing stored procedure.

So, It seems you have to provide partition key when you execute sp. Of course, it can be replaced by upsert function. It is useless from the perspective of the business logic, but if bulk operations, the SP can release some of the performance pressure because the SP is running on the server side.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes...thank you ....this is the documentation I referred to in my question. I am actually surprised that all the sample code provided for server-side use un-partitioned collections? This is not realistic. `Upsert` does not work for me....I have to query first to find the `id`...this is because the source docs are not pulled from Cosmos...so their `id` is not known.